# exchange 2010 - delivery reports - powershell

Tags: exchange, powershell

In ECP I can search for a message sent to a user and open up a delivery report. Specifically in the report I can see that after the message was delivered if it was then moved to a different folder in the user's mailbox due to a rule. I am trying to do this with powershell but don't get the same info. I've used get-messagetrackinglog, get-messagetrackingreport, search-messagetrackingreport but they just tell me if the user received it. Unlike the delivery report it won't tell me that the message was moved to another folder. Is there another command that I'm not aware of to get this info? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the `-RecipientPathFilter` and the `-ReportTemplate` options:

```
$reports = Search-MessageTrackingReport someone@yourdomain.com -BypassDelegateChecking:$true
foreach ($report in $reports)
{
  $r = Get-MessageTrackingReport $report.MessageTrackingReportId -RecipientPathFilter someone@yourdomain.com -ReportTemplate RecipientPath -BypassDelegateChecking:$true
  $r | Select-Object -Last 1 | % { $_.RecipientTrackingEvents }
}
```

Comment: Thanks longneck. That gives me what I needed. The key indeed were the 2 parameters you mention but also the "recipienttrackingevents" at the end. Without it it's not as readable and useful. I did have to break down your code to understand it. I also modified it a bit to make it make more sense to me. I ended up doing a "select-object -expandproperty recipienttrackingevents". Your scripting is definitely more advanced than mine. Thanks again.